# How to Bind json object in array sapui 5?

Tags: sapui5

My file **controller.js**,

Now want to bind json object in array using sapui 5. I am try below code for it.

```
onInit: function() {
        var elementArray=['ID','Name','Description','ReleaseDate','DiscontinuedDate','Rating','Price'];
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(elementArray);
        sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel,'fieldArray');

//      var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel('./smartappall/door.josn');
//      sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel,'approcords');
    },
```

**view.js**

```
var elementArray= bind fieldArray json model here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but since your model only contains the array, in your view you can do the following:

`var elementArray = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("fieldArray").getData();`

(EDITED: Forgot the `getData()` part...)

But generally, you don't store objects or arrays in a dedicated model, but rather have one model where you store them in separate properties. In that case, you can do:

In controller:

`sap.ui.getCore().getModel("fieldArray").setProperty("/pathToYourArray", elementArray");`

In view:

`var elementArray = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("fieldArray").getProperty("/pathToYourArray");`

Comment: I have an error : TypeError: sap.ui.getCore(...).getModel(...) is undefined.

Comment: There must be something wrong in your code, see this example: http://jsbin.com/pihucez/edit?html,js,output But keep in mind, you generally don't want to code **anything** in your view; all logic should be in the controller ;)

Comment: I think Stackoverflow doesn't allow posting private information, but you can just google 'qualiture' for my contact details ;)

Answer (score 0):

The JSONModel data must be a plain javascript object. IE not a javascript array.

You can either follow the previous answer and set your array as a property of the JSONModel, or modify your initial array to wrap it inside an object :

```
onInit: function() {
    var data = { elementArray: [
        'ID',
        'Name',
        'Description',
        'ReleaseDate',
        'DiscontinuedDate',
        'Rating',
        'Price'
    ]};
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(data);
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel,'fieldArray');

},
```

Then you can bind your view to {fieldArray>/elementArray}

Comment: While I completely agree a model should consist of key-values, you could perfectly use a simple array of strings in a JSONModel as well; in that case, you bind to `{fieldArray>/}` and the aggregation to `{fieldArray>}` _(and yes, it looks ugly as hell ;) )_